# Back out front of

Tags: word-usage

I just came across a phrase "back out front of" and couldn't understand what it meant:

> Back out front of the Seminar Hall and to the left.

A person asked "where's the bathroom?" So the other person was giving directions. Are these two separate phrases "back out" and "front of", like exit through the front door of the Seminar Hall and then turn left.

And what about:

> The original neon sign is back out front of The Chef”

It was in a post. "The Chef" is a restaurant.

Are there phrases where it is used?

Answer (score 2):

Directions will very frequently depend on gestures or on your hearer's knowledge of local geography, but it's easy enough to imagine circumstances in which the first sentence would be intelligible. For instance, if you're standing in a corridor leading to the *back* of the building you direct your hearer down that corridor to its end *out front of the Seminar Hall*—that is, outside the hall facing its entrance— the bathroom is now on your hearer's left, either on the same corridor or down another corridor leading to the left:

```
        SH               or                    SH
  ____/back\___                    __________/    \________
 |  out front   |                              back 
/     of SH     |                        out front of SH    
 ←BR            |               ___BR↓__                ______
 |              |                   \   |              |
 |              |                       |              |
 |              |                       |              |
 |              |                       |              |
```

ADDED: ColleenV points out that another possibility is “Go back the way you came from, until you get to the front of the seminar hall, then turn left”.

Your second sentence is a bit different. The word *original* suggests that what is meant is that the neon sign, which had been removed or replaced, is now *back* (restored) in its original position *out front of* the bar—that is, outside the bar on its front wall.

Comment: It could also mean, “go back the way you came from, until you get to the front of the seminar hall, then turn left”

Comment: @ColleenV A very good point. I'm'a steal it.

Comment: You can’t steal it! I already gave it to you. :)

Comment: @ColleenV Then I thank you -- as does, I trust, OP.

Comment: As your suggestion reads, "back" and "out front" are two different positions. **So shouldn't there be a comma between "back" and "out from"**, because they are referring to two different positions. We walk down the corridor (hallway), and we end up at the Seminar Hall.

Comment: And @ColleenV is the use of this phrase the easy you've pointed out common?

Comment: In directions, it’s very common to say “back up the road a bit and to your right”. Or “back to the street light”. “Back” can be tricky, like “this” and “that”. It’s sometimes related to the speaker’s location relative to where they’re sending you. We might also say “head up the road” if we’re telling you to keep going in the same direction, but there’s no rule for the exact situation where someone would pick back, up, down, etc. English is hard!

Comment: Here "back up" means "backing up" in the literal sense right, as in "reversing" @ColleenV

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Nope. “Up” is more connected to “the road” than back. I can say “up the road a bit” or “back along the road”.

Comment: So @CollenV what exactly do you mean by this sentence?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish "...shouldn't there be a comma...?" No. Whatever its mode of presentation, this is colloquial English, not written English, and in reliance on context it will tolerate an amazing degree of apparent ambiguity, without even intonation to disambiguate. "Look down underbeneath of the stairs on the right" is perfectly intelligible if you know the house.

Comment: It would be an elision of the following: *[Go] **back out** [the way you came and then go out] **front of the Seminar Hall and to the left**.*